# ExpandEnvironmentStrings( ... ) on a x64 bit windows is expanding %programfiles% to x86 path

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2015, environment-variables

I have an **x86** application running on a **x64** version of Windows 10.

In my app, I am using ExpandEnvironmentStrings( ... ) to expand a user given values.

But when the variable is **%programfiles%** it is expanded to **C:\Program Files (x86)**

Do I need to do something special to get an x86 app to expand the program file variable properly?

**NB**: when I use **%programfiles%** directly in explorer, it expands properly to **C:\Program Files**.

I am developing on Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When a 32-bit application expands the environment variable reference `%ProgramFiles%`, it always gets the folder path which contains by default the program folders of 32-bit applications. But this environment variable reference expands to folder path which contains by default the program folders of 64-bit applications when expanded from a 64-bit process (such as Windows Explorer).

The environment variable reference `%ProgramW6432%` must be used to get the program files folder path for 64-bit applications by a 32-bit process.

This is documented by Microsoft at [WOW64 Implementation Details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinProg64/wow64-implementation-details).

It is possible to check this by yourself by opening a 64-bit and a 32-bit command prompt – type `%SystemRoot%\SysWoW64\cmd.exe` to open a 32-bit command prompt on a 64-bit system. Then execute in both command prompt windows the command `set` for a complete list of environment variables with their current values or just `set prog` for a list of environment variables starting case-insensitive with string `prog` in name and their values.

See also Wikipedia article with the predefined [Windows Environment Variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows).